# Left outer join runtime error with LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to write a left outer join query with Linq on 2 tables, but getting NULL reference exception during runtime, when there are null values in the right table.

For all MatchID values as on tbl_Match table tbl_UserBets table does not have values for all. Hence when NULL value comes up, I'm getting run time exception

PFB my LINQ query,

```
string userID = "dfa3c0e7-2aa3-42ee-a7d3-803db902dc56";
var res2 = dbEntity.tbl_Match.Select(m => new
            {
                MatchID = m.MatchID,
                Team1 = m.Team1,
                Team2 = m.Team2,
                UserForTeam1 = dbEntity.tbl_UserBets.Where(b => b.UserForTeam1 == userID).FirstOrDefault(b => b.MatchID == m.MatchID),
                UserForTeam2 = dbEntity.tbl_UserBets.Where(b => b.UserForTeam2 == userID).FirstOrDefault(b => b.MatchID == m.MatchID)
            });

            foreach (var item in res2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.MatchID + " " + item.Team1 + " vs " + item.Team2 + " " + item.UserForTeam1 == null ? " NA " : item.UserForTeam1.UserForTeam1);
            }
```

SQL Table design for tbl_Match table:

```
Create Table tbl_Match(
MatchID int primary key Identity,
TournamentID int Foreign key references tbl_Tournament(TournamentID),
Team1 int Foreign key references tbl_TournamentTeams(TeamID),
Team2 int Foreign key references tbl_TournamentTeams(TeamID),
StartTime DateTime not null,
MatchBetAmount int not null
);
```

SQL Table design for tbl_UserBets table:

```
Create Table tbl_UserBets(
UserBetSlNo int primary key identity,
TournamentID int Foreign key references tbl_Tournament(TournamentID),
MatchID int Foreign key references tbl_Match(MatchID),
UserForTeam1 nvarchar(128) Foreign key references AspNetUsers(Id),
UserForTeam2 nvarchar(128) Foreign key references AspNetUsers(Id),
UserForNoBets nvarchar(128) Foreign key references AspNetUsers(Id)
);
```

With the below query in SQL i'm able to get the results properly, Need to do the same with LINQ.

```
select DISTINCT(tbl_Match.MatchID),tbl_Match.Team1,tbl_Match.Team2,tbl_Match.StartTime,tbl_Match.MatchBetAmount,tbl_UserBets.UserForTeam1,tbl_UserBets.UserForTeam2,tbl_UserBets.UserForNoBets from tbl_Match left outer join tbl_UserBets on tbl_Match.MatchID = tbl_UserBets.MatchID and (tbl_UserBets.UserForTeam1 = 'dfa3c0e7-2aa3-42ee-a7d3-803db902dc56' or tbl_UserBets.UserForTeam2 = 'dfa3c0e7-2aa3-42ee-a7d3-803db902dc56')
```

Please let me know, what changes i should be doing to fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

try merging the where condition with the first or default

i'm guessing the problem is when the where returns null the first or default will cause the exception as [stated by msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var res2 = dbEntity.tbl_Match.Select(m => new
            {
                MatchID = m.MatchID,
                Team1 = m.Team1,
                Team2 = m.Team2,
                UserForTeam1 = dbEntity.tbl_UserBets.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserForTeam1 == userID && b.MatchID == m.MatchID),
                UserForTeam2 = dbEntity.tbl_UserBets.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserForTeam2 == userID && b.MatchID == m.MatchID)
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for replying on my query. The issue was with how i was concatenating the null value with other string values in console.writeline within foreach loop, bcoz of which i was getting null pointer exception. Once i moved the logic to check if the value is null before the loop. It solved the issue.

Comment: no problem ,, i'll leave my answear maybe help some1 else with the issue i described